# Storing the mean square resulted from CVlm

Tags: r

I am trying to create a script in R for automatically assessing the predictive power of various possible linear models. To assess the predictive power of a model, I use as a quality indicator their overall mean square which comes from a cross-validation for which I use the function CVlm from package DAAG. My question is how can I retrieve the value of the overall mean square resulted from CVlm in an automated way (without having to observed the textual output of CVlm)?

For example the following code from http://maths-people.anu.edu.au/~johnm/r-book/3edn/scripts/reg1.R

```
houseprices.lm <- lm(sale.price ~ area, data=houseprices) 
CVlm(houseprices, houseprices.lm, plotit=TRUE)
```

has an output in the form

fold 1
Observations in test set: ...

fold 2
Observations in test set: ...

Overall ms
2023

How can I access/store the value of ms (2023) of each run?

Comment: The question is not clear , do you want to store all the folds or just the number ms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to store the result of `CVlm` in a variable and access the `ms` attribute:

```
houseprices.lm <- lm(sale.price ~ area, data=houseprices) 
cv <- CVlm(houseprices, houseprices.lm, plotit=TRUE) 
attr(cv, "ms")
# [1] 3934
```

Comment: How come this isn't available as e.g. `cv$ms`? The object created by `lm` behaves this way.

Comment: @kermit666: `ms` is an attribute. That's why you have to access it via `attr(cv, "ms")`. `$ms` only works for columns (e.g. in `data.frame`) or named elements (e.g. in `list`).